# Dynamically create new DataFrames from unique row names

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to create new dataframes using the unique row names from an existing dataframe.

I want to take the names in "Unicos" and use them to create the new dataframes, to add all the information I want in each individual dataframe after that.

But clearly I have no idea of how to do this..
Does anyone have any idea?

```
Unicos <- unique(df$INTERFASE)
x = 0
for (i in Unicos){
  x = x + 1
  Unicos[x] <- subset(TraficoPorInterfaz, INTERFASE == toString(Unicos[x]))
}
```

Comment: Consider `by`: `Unicos_df_list <- by(df, df$INTERFASE, identity)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your for loop, you are overwriting `Unicos` with a data subset, but the loop itself is iterating through the values in `Unicos`.

You can create new data frames and store them in a list that is as long as `Unicos` like so:

```
Unicos <- unique(df$INTERFASE)
new_dfs <- lapply(Unicos, function(x) subset(TraficoPorInterfaz, INTERFASE == toString(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R has the `split` function, which will split your dataframe based on values within a column. Splitting a dataframe gives you a named list of dataframes, which I think is your desired output.

Not positive without a sample of your data, but `split(df, df$INTERFASE)` should work. Each item in the list will be a dataframe that's the subset of `df` with a given value of `df$INTERFASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of data.frames with each element of the list being one value of `INTERFASE`

```
L = split(TraficoPorInterfaz, TraficoPorInterfaz$INTERFASE)
```

If you want them in your global environment

```
list2env(L, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```